# Aurelia: rendering objects fetched from server in repeater and bind them with parent

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am trying to fetch a list of objects (JSON) from the server, then render them in a repeater, and have a click handler on each of those items to be handled by the parent view model. So far I have:

```
/* list.html */
<template>
  <require from="./components/player.html"></require>
  <div>
    <player repeat.for="p of players" containerless player-data.bind="p" dosth.call="dosth(p)"></player>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then the player custom element:

```
/* player.html */
<template>
  ${playerData.name}
  <button click.delegate="dosth()">DO STH</button>
<template>
```

And the player model:

```
/* player.ts */
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('player')
export class PlayerModel {
  @bindable playerData: any;
  @bindable dosth;

  bind(ctxt: any) {
    console.log(ctxt);
  }
}
```

When I receive data from server:

```
return this.http.fetch('players')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(players => {
      for (let p of players) {
        var model = new PlayerModel();
        model.playerData = p;
        this.players.push(model);
      }
  });
```

Where `this.players` is an array property in the list.ts view model.

I have 2 issues:

1. My `bind` method on the `PlayerModel` is not triggered - why?
2. I can't get the dosth function to work. I am getting 'dosth' is not a function error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading an HTML-Only custom element. If you have a view-model (in your case `player.ts`), you must require the custom element without `.html`. Like this:

```
<require from="./components/player"></require> <!-- no .html here -->
```

In addition, `containerless` in html markup only works for html-only custom elements. In your case, you must declare `containerless` in your view-model. Like this:

```
import {customElement, bindable, containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';

@containerless
@customElement('player')
export class PlayerModel {
  @bindable playerData: any;
  @bindable dosth;

  bind(ctxt: any) {
    console.log(ctxt);
  }
}
```

More information at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/2

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I am almost there. Now the last part (I think) is that ${playerData.name} is not rendered in the page. Any hints on this? I can see that in the PlayerModel.bin I need to inspect `this.player.player` to get the playerData object.

Comment: That's because in your function, you are doing  `var model = new PlayerModel(); model.playerData = p;  this.players.push(model);`. You should be doing something like this: `let model = new PlayerModel(p); this.players.push(model);`

Comment: Or perhaps `player-data.bind="p.playerData"`

Comment: So `player-data.bind="p.playerData"` did the trick. I just don't understand (yet) why I need to explicitly tell Aurelia that I want to bind `player-data` (which maps to playerData field) to `p.playerData`. I thought this will be just a property of the view model, which I can use in the view (hence the original `${playerData.name}` which I added to my view). Aurelia definitely needs more examples and explanations on the docs page. Anyway thanks a lot Fabio!